# SQL history record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I am a bit new to SQL.

I am just curious that if SQL server can:

1. track what script it has been ran against it.

For example:
if I have an old SQL database, I want to know what script has been run against it so I know what data has been changed.

It can be a table to record history of the name of the scripts or what data has been changed.

Can it be done in SQL?

Comment: Look into change data capture to keep track of what data that has changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
USE master
SELECT [text]
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans AS p
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(p.plan_handle)
```

It pull the information from cache If SQL Server hasn't been restarted.

Otherwise you need a third party tool like [Apex Sql](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx) or [SSMS Tool Pack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Features?f=3)

I have tested for SQL Server 2012 but it should work for 2008 and 2014 also